# I have written a line in nano /etc/my.cnf file and how I'm not able to remove it

Tags: mysql

I have added `secure-file-priv = ""` to my nano /etc/my.cnf file for mysql and now I'm not able to remove it.[When I remove that line and try to save it, it's asking me to write to a file and the changes are not saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J93Hv.png)

I tried to uninstall and install mySQL but due to this the server is not able to start.

```
Error Messages:
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1.
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Starting MySQL
.my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1.
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1.
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

Is there any way I can fix this error, I tried a lot but couldn't find any solution

Comment: Add empty group. For example, [mysqld].

Comment: I have added, but it’s not allowing me to save the file, when I do a control+x on my mac to save, it then prompted for y or n. I have selected y and then it asked me to write to a file where it’s throws error when I provide the same file path as read only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"errors when saving" are often linked to *access rights* issues.

- run `ls -l /etc/my.cnf` to confirm that this file is owned by `root`.
- in the vast majority of cases, system wide configuration files are owned by `root`. To edit a `root` file, you should do it with root privileges, e.g :

```
sudo nano /etc/my.cnf
```

(that's probably how you were able to add the config parameter in the first place)

Comment: Yes, the file is owned by root. Using `sudo nano /etc/my.cnf` I was able to remove the line added by me. Thank You

Comment: ok. There should be an error message printed by nano, something like `[ Error writing myfile: Permission denied ]` when failing to save the file. *That's* the relevant information, to both your issue and your question.